# NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject not working

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject is called but the getter returns variable 'a' as nil. It's annoying me.

Anyone see what the problem is here ?

```
let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("Information.ab")

var info: Information? {
        get {
            let a = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: url.absoluteString) as? Information
            return a
        }
        set {
            if info != newValue && newValue != nil {
                NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(newValue as Any, toFile: url.absoluteString)
            }
        }
    }

class Information: RecordModel {

    let rules: CKAsset
    let aboutUs: String
    let terms: String
    let privacyPolicy: String

    override init(record: CKRecord) {
        rules = record["rules"] as! CKAsset
        aboutUs = record["aboutUs"] as! String
        terms = record["terms"] as! String
        privacyPolicy = record["privacyPolicy"] as! String
        super.init(record: record)
    }

}

class RecordModel: NSObject, NSCoding {

    let record: CKRecord

    init(record: CKRecord) {
        self.record = record
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let record = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "keyRecord") as! CKRecord
        self.init(record: record)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(record, forKey: "keyRecord")
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let rhs = object as? Information {
            return record.recordID == rhs.record.recordID
        }
        return false
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        return record.recordID.hashValue
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `unarchiveObject(withFile` and `archiveRootObject(_:toFile` expect a file **path** without the `file://` scheme, so it's in both cases

```
url.path
```

rather than <strike>url.absoluteString</strike>